# Multiple OR conditions are not working with Rules

Tags: 7, rules

Multiple OR conditions are not working with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module in Drupal 7.

I have profile2 module. And I want to notify user with an email if one of the fields from the user's profile is empty, I have written a rule but multiple OR conditions are not working.

Any help?

Comment: can u please provide the rule event,conditions and actions elaborately or provide the rule export

Comment: event "After user has logged in"

Comment: Event : "After user has logged in" ,    Condition : "data value is empty OR data value is empty" , Action : "send html mail" if any of the profile field is empty.

Comment: use rules debugger to debug the execution of your rule..eg) to check whether the condition returns true,acion gets executec or not.you can enable debugger in /admin/config/workflow/rules/settings

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a bug report to a third-party module and this bug should be reported in the mentioned module's issue queue on drupal.org not here.

Comment: It's not a bug report. Almost certainly this is configuration error. Without an export we can't be sure because a verbal description of the configuration is insufficient. But saying 'Condition : "data value is empty OR data value is empty"' implies that the condition was set up improperly - there should be an OR condition followed by (indented) data value is empty, followed by (indented) data value is empty. If the OR is between the two conditions, and if the OR is at the same level of indentation, then what you really have is an AND of THREE conditions, one of which is the empty OR.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and found out that it is working fine for `main profile` but if you create any other profile it is not working. I debugged and found out that it is throwing exception `unable to get the data property as the parent data structure is not set` while executing the `function value()` in `entity.wrapper.inc` which is called from `function rules_condition_data_is_empty($data)`. I will debug it further when I have time, but as of now I hope this helps.